# Data Segment in Compiler Construction

Tags: compiler-construction, data-segment, vm-implementation

i am developing a **compiler** for my own defined language , i have generated **3 address code** and now i am going to develop a **virtual machine** which can run that 3 address code. but for that i need Data Segment (where i can store all of my variables values) .i have two data types in my language (int and char) .
please give me a hint that how can i construct a data segment where i can store all of my variables (int and char both) values
thanks reading my problem

Comment: What architecture are you targeting?

Comment: @HunterMcMillen My reading of the question indicates he's writing the "machine"...

Comment: @michaelb958 i am just writing a compiler for a language which i myself give name BCP language  i have gone through these phases
1- LA
2-Parser
3-Translation 

now i am no interpreter part

Answer (score 2):

I strongly recommend to **read** [C.Queinnec's book *Lisp In Small Pieces*](http://pagesperso-systeme.lip6.fr/Christian.Queinnec/WWW/LiSP.html); it explains very well a lot of things related to your questions.

<sup>While C.Queinnec's book focus apparently on Lisp-like languages, it teach you concepts which you can apply to a lot of other languages, including your own. In particular, you'll want to formalize more the [denotational semantics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denotational_semantics) or [operational semantics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_semantics) of your language.</sup>

You could also at least study some VM, including [Ocaml virtual machine](http://cadmium.x9c.fr/distrib/caml-instructions.pdf), [JVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine), [Parrot VM](http://www.parrot.org/), [NekoVM](http://nekovm.org/), [LUA VM](http://www.lua.org/)...

And you may later want to use just in time compilation techniques, notably with [LLVM](http://llvm.org/) or [libjit](http://freecode.com/projects/libjit) etc...

See also http://lambda-the-ultimate.org/

BTW, you may find much more convenient to have your language implementation reuse some existing VM.

I don't grasp why is a data segment such an issue. Your VM usually starts with some heap image, which contain both data and bytecode. A lot of languages have (at least implicitly) [closures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_science%29) - or at least [objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_%28computer_science%29) - mixing code and data.